# " write a python program to marks of 3 students and print student's data in descending order based on average and grade."

Tags: python, loops

my teacher give me this assignment
" write a python program to read name and marks of math, English, and physics of 3 students and print student's data in descending order based on average and grade."
he want us to write it with these command (loops,if statment,print,input)
no functions

i'm stuck here

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    name = input("enter the student's name: ")
    math = int(input("enter the Math mark: "))
    eng = int(input("enter the English mark: "))
    ph = int(input("enter the Physics mark: "))
    Av = ((math + eng + ph) / 3)
    print(name, Av, "%")
```

how can i compare the entered values in loop?

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save all values in a `list`, to be able to sort them for printing them afterward

```
values = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    name = input("enter the student's name: ")
    math = int(input("enter the Math mark: "))
    eng = int(input("enter the English mark: "))
    ph = int(input("enter the Physics mark: "))
    values.append((name, math, eng, ph, (math + eng + ph) / 3))

values.sort(key=lambda x: x[4], reverse=True)
for row in values:
    print(*row)
```

Comment: For what is it the `*` operator inside print?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre It expand the list, to print each element of `value` as separate one, and not the list as once. Try with and without you'll see ;)

Comment: `for v in [('suhail',3,4),('sumesh',5,6)]: print(*v)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly, you must gather names and scores, and then compare them.

```py
from statistics import mean

student_scores = {}

for i in range(0, 3):
    name = input("enter the student's name: ")
    math = int(input("enter the Math mark: "))
    eng = int(input("enter the English mark: "))
    ph = int(input("enter the Physics mark: "))

    student_scores[name] = mean([math, eng, ph])

for name, avg_score in sorted(stduent_scores.items(), key=lambda d: d[1], reverse=True):
    print(f"{name}: {avg_score}")
```